# Connecting 2 Sales Cloud Salesforce Organizations

Tags: salesforce

We are looking to run two sales cloud orgs, the intention being that we want two groups of users working from similar data sets, but we cannot have them in the same instance even with sharing settings set up. We don't want the data to get stale, so we are looking for a way to connect these orgs and update specific objects. For instance, if, in Instance A, an address for a contact is updated, we want instance B to reflect that as soon as possible.

Curious if anyone has done this or has another solution that has worked for them?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to solve it without writing any code so you might have more luck asking on dedicated https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/. And consider asking your SF account representative too or even some consultancy/SF partner, it's an architecture question...

There used to be something called [Salesforce to Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=business_network_intro.htm&language=en_US&type=5) (S2S), no idea if it's still actively suggested to new clients. From what I remember it works only in productions, you can't try it out in sandbox.

There's "Lightning Connect", paid extra but allows seeing (and editing) data that doesn't physically sit in your org. Even reporting and access from Apex code if needed, it's almost invisible to the developer that network traffic is involved. It uses OData protocol and is fairly easy to set up with SF authentication (click click click, no coding needed). You'd grant create/read/update/delete rights like you normally do, on the Profile.

You could look into something fancier like "hub and spokes" architecture, not "point to point". If you have some existing "Master Data Management", "360 view", "customer's golden record" blah blah blah... Maybe the answer is to have orgs connecting to this instead of each other.

There's also some noise about SF's own product for that, search for "Salesforce CDP"

And worst case you could build some config (flows? search for "external services") or coded Apex callouts to send the updates around...